# Related List Links Rendered in Output Panel Not Working

Tags: visualforce

I have two custom objects with M-D relationship. Below is a Visualforce page with two radio buttons to allow a user to toggle. Different fields will be displayed depends on which radio button is chosen. If the user chooses “App” button, the detail page will be displayed along with the related list. The problem I encountered is that when I click on any of the links in the related list, none of the links were working.

> ![When I checked on the Console, I got this error: Refused to display
>   'https://cs8.salesforce.com/a0lL0000004yg6y' in a frame because it set
>   'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'. VFDevModeWithViewstate.js:21](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RDyw.jpg)

Thanks in advance for your help!

```
<apex:page standardController="App__c">
<apex:sectionHeader subtitle="Application"/>
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock tabStyle="App__c">
        <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" Title="Choose One:">
            <apex:selectRadio value="{!App__c.showApp__c}" label="">
                <apex:selectOption itemLabel="App" itemValue="Y"/>
                <apex:selectOption itemLabel="No App" itemValue="N"/>
                <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="appPanelContainer" />
            </apex:selectRadio>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>                
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
<apex:outputPanel id="appPanelContainer">
    <apex:outputPanel id="appPanel" rendered="{!App__c.showApp__c == 'Y'}"> 
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
                <apex:detail subject="{!App__c.Id}" relatedList="false" relatedListHover="true" inlineEdit="true"/>
                <apex:relatedList List="App_Items__r" subject="{!App__c.Id}" />
            </apex:pageBlockSection>                
        </apex:pageBlock>                
    </apex:outputPanel>
    <apex:outputPanel id="noappPanel" rendered="{!App__c.showApp__c == 'N'}"> 
        <apex:form >
            <apex:pageBlock >
                <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">
                    <apex:commandButton action="{!Save}" value="Save"/>
                    <apex:commandButton action="{!Cancel}" value="Cancel"/>
                </apex:pageBlockButtons>
                <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!App__c.No_App__c}"/>
                </apex:pageBlockSection>                
            </apex:pageBlock>                
        </apex:form>
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:outputPanel>
```